# 3 transistors connected in series principle?

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, schematics

My teacher asked me what is the principle behind this circuit, And i don't know what does he means, what are your thoughts ?.

[image]

Comment: Cascading? Amplification?

Comment: Looks like kind of multistage amplifier. Though Darlington at first too, but it has a common collector

Comment: Ask your teacher. Don't be shy, just go up to him and ask him (use your magnificent_power).

Comment: What sort of current do you want flowing through the LED? 10mA? 100mA? So what's the current needed into the base of the last transistor? So what's the current needed into the base of the middle transistor? So what's the current needed into the base of the first transistor?

Comment: Current amplification, perhaps? "The meaning of hFE" maybe?

Comment: This circuit is seen in homemade 'mains sniffers'. Instead of seeing the 2.1V as an input, consider it as the bias supply. Then you can consider the input to be the current that will go into the first transistor's base via capacitive coupling with an electrode placed on the node where the 1k resistor is. The LED will light up when the circuit (the electrode) comes near a 110V or 230V line. (and if you are into paranormal, you can call this a 'ghost detector' :-) )

Comment: What is a Current Amplifier switch gain ? 10% of rated hFE at Vce(sat)  These are Emitter Followers or Common Emitters. Rce Leakage (Early Effect) must be suppressed by Base to ground R to turn off if desired. Q1,Q2 are redundant and offer no gain with Rc and saturated switch

Answer (score 4):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4Nxl8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let's make some assumptions first for making the analysis quite simple.

1. The LED requires current of 100mA for glowing.
2. All three transistors are identical with gain = 100 for each transistor.

3.The base-emitter (Vbe) is 0.7V for each of the transistors.

4. I am going to give a theoretical insight of how this circuit works.

Lets start our analysis from Q3. The current needed to glow the LED up is 100mA. This is the collector current for Q3. Since the transistor has gain of 100, the base current required is 100mA/100 (=1mA). This current should be supplied by the transistor Q2.

Into Q2 now. The emitter current should be 1mA for this transistor. The emitter current is a sum of collector current and base current. We can neglect the base current. So, the emitter current is equal to collector current now. And you can see the colletor current for Q2 is 1mA. Since this transistor also has gain of 100, the base current is now 1mA/100 (=0.01mA). This base current is supplied by Q1.

Repeating the same analysis for Q1, you can see that the collector current for Q1 is 0.01mA and the base current is 0.01mA/100 (= 0.0001=10uA). The current through the R4 resistor is 100nA. Note this current.

Now, lets see what is the voltage at B1.

The transistor turns on only when the base emitter voltage is just enough to allow required current to flow into base of the transistor. I have mentioned above this voltage to be 0.7V. So, for Q3 to turn on, the node B3 must be 0.7V higher than its emitter. Since the emitter is connected to 0V, the value for B3=0.7V.

Now, looking at Q2, it has its emitter tied to B3 which is at 0.7V. So the transistor can turn on only when the base voltage is 0.7V greater than the emitter voltage. i.e B2=1.4V.

For Q3, the emitter is tied to B2 so, the emitter is sitting at 1.4V. Repeating the same procedure as above, the base has to be at 2.1V. So, B1=2.1V.

The resistor R4 comes to play now. It needs to supply 10uA current. So, the voltage across it has to be 10uA * 1k = 10mV. Since one end of resistor is tied to 2.1V (=2100mV), another end should be connected to 2.11v(=2110mV). You can argue that it is almost impossible to have such precise voltage supply and it's valid if we look at the real-world scenario. But, I am just considering a theoretical aspect of the problem.

Comment: I realize these are "for illustration" numbers, but 100 mA will cause most LEDs to fry, not "glow", won't it?

Comment: Yeah. You are absolutely right. Typically LEDs take about 10-20 mA during full brightness as far as I know.

Comment: The collector current of Q1 is 10µA, so the base current through R4 is only 100nA.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

### This is a Darlington 2-stage emitter follower + common emitter (CE) "Switch" LED driver with current limited R's.

**Emitter Followers are current buffers with unity voltage AC gain.**

Demonstrated below with a triangle input 0 to 3.3V  . The cost reduced driver on right side has proper R Ratios and a DC offset for signal to show you symmetry for resistor values and currents required.

[image]
Each transistor  Vbe. is show with peak upper/lower values.

Vbe controls max. collector current by definition until device specs are exceeded but to self-heating bulk resistance.

"Early Effect"= Rce leakage is ignored here but demands Vbe is low for full turn off, but I added 100k to show how one might compensate for turn off leakage with a pull down R.

So, I used a 3.3V triangle wave to [demonstrate](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%2016.13108636308289%2060%2015%2053%0Aw%20640%20160%20640%20144%200%0At%20608%20176%20640%20176%200%201%20-4.979785491562314%200.000001054133815626549%20100%0Aw%20688%20192%20640%20192%203%0Ag%20688%20192%20688%20224%200%0AR%20640%2064%20640%2032%200%200%2040%204.98%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20640%20112%20640%20144%200%201000%0AR%20352%20144%20352%20112%200%203%2030%201.66%201.66%200%200.159154943092%0A162%20640%2064%20640%20112%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0Ar%20480%2064%20480%20128%200%201000%0At%20432%20144%20480%20144%200%201%20-4.947795996535949%20-0.08777195835774487%20100%0At%20528%20160%20560%20160%200%201%20-4.860024027842612%200.1199749075846227%20100%0Ar%20560%2064%20560%20144%200%201000%0Ar%20352%20144%20416%20144%200%201000%0Aw%20432%20144%20416%20144%203%0Aw%20528%20160%20480%20160%203%0Aw%20608%20176%20560%20176%203%0Aw%20560%2064%20640%2064%200%0Aw%20480%2064%20560%2064%200%0A403%20176%2096%20304%20160%200%206_64_0_4098_5_0.00009765625_0_2_6_3%0A403%20672%20128%20800%20192%200%207_64_0_4354_2.5_0.1_0_2_7_3%0A403%20672%2064%20800%20128%200%207_64_0_12545_0.0001_0.0032811584742238175_0_2_7_3%0Ar%20560%20176%20560%20224%200%20100000%0Ag%20560%20224%20560%20256%200%0Ax%20452%2034%20571%2037%204%2012%20hFE%5Cq100%5Cs%5Cs(fixed%5Csideal)%0Aw%201008%20176%20992%20176%203%0Ar%20928%20176%20992%20176%200%2010000%0A162%201040%2064%201040%20112%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0AR%20928%20176%20928%20144%200%203%2030%201.66%200.8133999999999999%200%200.159154943092%0Ar%201040%20112%201040%20144%200%201000%0AR%201040%2064%201040%2032%200%200%2040%204.98%200%200%200.5%0Aw%201040%20208%201040%20192%203%0At%201008%20176%201040%20176%200%201%20-5.794297375735511%20-0.8143959957302548%20100%0Aw%201040%20160%201040%20144%200%0Ag%201040%20208%201040%20224%200%0A403%201056%2032%201184%2096%200%2026_64_0_45313_0.0001_0.0032233813420535014_0_2_26_3%0A403%201056%20112%201184%20160%200%2032_64_0_4354_5_0.1_0_2_32_3%0A403%20848%2064%20976%20128%200%2027_64_0_20738_2.5_0.1_0_2_27_3%0Ao%209%2064%204%2012546%200.6425726469559552%200.0001%200%201%0Ao%2010%2064%204%2012546%200.6636016427083722%200.0001%200%201%0Ao%201%2064%204%2012546%200.6746508265495594%200.0001%200%201%0Ao%207%2064%200%2012545%200.0001%200.003281158474227326%200%202%207%203%0Ao%206%2064%200%2012546%203.3199999998812797%200.0001%200%202%206%203%0A38%204%200%203%2012%20Voltage%0A38%2027%202%200%201.66%20DC%5CsOffset%0A) **the Darlington 2-stage + common emitter Switch 3rd stage** at 50% duty cycle.  What is Vrms?  The Thevenin ideal midpoint voltage for 1k to get 50% duty cycle from AC.

Answer (score -1):

Given the Vbe will reduce by 0.058 volts per decades of current, the 3 transistors might all be in saturation, or on the verge of saturation.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to the question - or not one that the OP will understand. Did you intend to make a comment?